# how to use setModelValue(); in wicket 6. x or 7.x?

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wicket-6, wicket-1.6, wicket-7

In wicket 1.4.9 setModelValue("") was accepting string as a parameter, but in 1.5 it need String Array,
I have code as shown below, anybody knows how to modify setModelValue("") to 6.x or 7.x.

```
if (!onlineVerfStatus) {
    TextField captcha = class.getValue("captcha");    

    captchaDisplayTxt.setModelObject(generateCaptcha());

    captcha.clearInput();
    captcha.setModelValue("");



    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`captcha.setModelValue(new String[] {""});`

Comment: Thank you martin. it got fixed my issue.